# adding subfolders to java folder in android studio 1.0.2

Tags: android, android-studio

Inside the java folder I have different java classes: one main activity, several fragments and others are utilities and asynctasks.

How can I re-order them inside sub folders inside the java folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create packages in your project to maintain java classes.

[image]

Comment: First, I'm talking about android studio and not eclipse. All are under the same package java->com.example.example but I want to make folders for organizational purpose only so it will look clean.So under com.example.example I will have "fragments" and "utils" folders (for example) and inside I will put the relevant java classes

Answer (score 3):

Can't believe there is no straightforward answer on the internet even though it is pretty simple:

FOR ANDROID STUDIO

1. Right click on your main package ("*com.example.android.myapp*")
2. Select **New** -> **Package**
3. Enter the name of the 'folder' you want to create and click **OK**.
   If your package name is "com.example.android.myapp," then enter "com.example.android.myapp.folderName" as the folder name.

There you have it - A new 'folder' inside your main src folder.

Answer (score 0):

Make new packages, and import them as needed. Or right click and select "show in explorer" and make your folders there.

Comment: Import? I'm talking about creating sub folders below the package com.example.example

Comment: In java those are packages. Also you can try my second option